# How does module path resolution work for functions in react native library?

Tags: react-native

I've noticed that files inside the `react-native/Libraries` can be imported without specifying the full path.
Like,

```
const EdgeInsetsPropType = require('react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/EdgeInsetsPropType');
```

Is the same as,
`const EdgeInsetsPropType = require('EdgeInsetsPropType');`
How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the `EdgeInsetsPropType` module, those should be the same thing. The reason that you can import that module directly by its name is because of [this line](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/EdgeInsetsPropType.js#L9).

The `@providesModule EdgeInsetsPropType` comment is what makes it so you can import it directly. Here is a good basic explanation of why `@providesModule` works the way it does.

> The packager uses two methods to look up modules. The first is based
>   on docblock headers: if you write "@providesModule X" in the first
>   docblock this enables require('X'). The other method is Node's
>   resolution.

This description was taken from [this comment on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/896#issuecomment-93965355).